# Access Word 'Save As' dialog box with PowerShell script

Tags: pdf, powershell, ms-word, ms-office, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a PowerShell script (running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) that opens a Word doc in Word 2010, performs a SaveAs, and saves the doc as a PDF. In brief my code looks similar to the below:

```
$word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"
$word.Visible = $true
$doc = $word.documents.open("path\file.doc")
$doc.SaveAs("path\file.pdf", [ref] 17)
$doc.Close()
ps winword | kill
```

The above works fine, no problems at all and is converting the documents as expected.

My question is:

If I physically open Word myself and navigate to 'File > Save As' I get various options in the dialog when saving as PDF (eg. page range, optimisation etc)

How can I, if at all, access these options from within the PowerShell script when performing the same action?

Any advice would be appreciated. Maybe it's just not possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is properly a question about the Word COM API, not Powershell specifically. It is an interesting question though. If I have time today I might look into it.

Comment: Thanks EBGreen. That would be appreciated, and beneficial for others seeking the same thing I imagine as I was unable to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much investigation I've found that option I needed was ExportAsFixedFormat().

The documentation can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx

And you can see it in action within a PowerShell script here:

http://blog.coolorange.com/2012/04/20/export-word-to-pdf-using-powershell/